# Quality of proof of elementary set theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

A *very* simple theorem in set theory, and my attempt at a proof. I've always struggled with proofs, and as such am going back to basics and working up from there. How would you rate the  quality of the proof?

- Does the argument follow?
- Is it presented OK (i.e. understand, and aesthetically mathematical?

**Theorem.**
$\ A \cup (B \cup C) = (A \cup B) \cup C$.

**Proof:** Let$\ x \in  A \cup (B \cup C) $. Use the definition of union, namely that if$\ x \in A \cup B$, then$\ x \in A$ or$\ x \in B$. So$\ x \in A \cup (B \cup C)$:

- implies$\ x \in A$ or$\ x \in (B \cup C)$,
- which implies$\ x \in A$ or $\ x \in B$ or $\ x \in C$,
- which implies$\ x \in (A \cup B)$ or$\ x \in C$ ,
- which implies$\ x \in (A \cup B) \cup C$, as required.

Comment: This is a correct proof that the left hand side is *contained* in the right hand side. To prove they are *equal* you now need to start from $x\in(A\cup B)\cup C$ and prove that $x\in A\cup(B\cup C) $. Which is pretty much more of what you've already done.

Comment: Thanks very much @user8734617. How detailed does my proof of the other direction have to be? (see my reply to the answer below)

Comment: It depends on the context. I guess you are being asked to demonstrate your knowledge of sets and their relations: I wouldn't risk it and I would write the full proof in the other direction, just in case. You can also use the symbol for equivalence ($\iff$, MathJax \iff) and write the whole proof in both directions at once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've only showed one direction of the inclusion. You still technically need to state why $(A \cup B) \cup C \subset A \cup (B \cup C)$.
The argument is analogous completely though.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes the first inclusion follows.
2. I wouldn't use indexed lined to present implications, rather use $ \implies$ between each line:)

Comment: Thank you @Mariah. I'll employ the ⟹ from now on :). So you'd end with:

"So $\ A \cup (B \cup C) \subseteq (A \cup B) \cup C $.

And $\ (A \cup B) \cup C  \subseteq A \cup (B \cup C)$
through the same logic."

Or is second sentence too vague?

And do I want$\ \subseteq$ or$\ \subset$ in these two sentences?

Comment: @iWebb I guess it depends on the context of your work; if this is a beginners class in set theory or something similar you should go ahead and present the other inclusion. However, in more advanced contexts such an argument would be taken to be obvious. The two inclusion symbols are the same, I'm not aware of a difference between them.

Comment: Thank you for you advice @Mariah. With regards the notation, I thought that$\ \subseteq$ denotes a subset of a set that could be equal to the set, whilst$\ \subset$ denotes a subset that cannot be equal to the set (i.e. a proper subset). This is backed up by the LaTex code: '\subseteq' for the former and '\subset' for the latter.

Comment: @iWebb $\subsetneq$ is the symbol for a proper subset. I don't think $\subset$ refers to a proper subset in most conventions.